# Access jQuery variable outside of IIFE

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function( global, factory ) {
    var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {

    return jQuery;
}));

jQuery('body').click();
```

I try to study how jquery work and I have a question about IIFE

jQuery wrap insdie of IIFE, how come we still can use var jQuery this variable outside of IIFE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because at end of source there is a line that assigns it to global window space:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Comment: so while we create our own function, do u suggest we do this way too?

Comment: Really depends on what you are doing. Typically you want to avoid polluting global namespace